# Display icon dynamically on top of every image

Tags: javascript, json

I am fetching multiple images from JSON dynamically & displaying those images in html page, on top of every image, i want to display an icon....

**Issue** :

But Icon is displaying only on single image....

Here is codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RdMrxy

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/50uzda24/

Below is code snippet :

```js
var target;
var font = "<img src = 'https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png'>";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "name": "L2a"
            },
            {
                "x": 160,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 0,
                        "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
                        "y": 0,
                        "name": "L2b-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 188,
                        "y": 122,
                        "name": "L2b-2"
                    }

                ],
                "y": 291,
                "name": "user_image_1"
            },
            {
                "x": 25,
                "layers": [{
                        "x": 0,
                        "src": "hEM2kEP.png",
                        "y": 0,
                        "name": "L2C-1"
                    },
                    {
                        "x": 209,
                        "y": 136,
                        "name": "L2C-2"
                    }
                ],
                "y": 22,
                "name": "L2"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612,
        "name": "L1"
    }]
};



$(document).ready(function() {

    // upload image onclick

    $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }

    });

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y
            } of arr) {

            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                font: font,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                font: font,
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                font: font,
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }

    json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };



            }, 20);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            console.log("load");
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };

        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 
}

.container img
 {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:250px;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
 
 z-index:999;
 }

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

<img src = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png">

</div>
```

Comment: This is way to much code for what you're trying to do. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: @Arthur thanks for suggestion, i already filtered many unwanted lines of code and kept the required code, there is `jq plugin` code is there, you can ignore that code, if i dont include that `jq plugin` code, then image will not display, but  i will check one more time & try to keep less code....

Comment: This is why the Help Center tell you to `Restart from scratch. Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem`. You don't need `jq plugin` or even any Javascript to solve your HTML/CSS problem (Display and position are for css, javascript is for events and computing data). Your JS are only to build Html and are irrelevant here.

Comment: @Arthur sure, i will try my best to keep the less code & i will edit the question soon....

Comment: @vickeycolors You don't have a code that displays the icon.
You see an icon near by the first image only because of this line in your html: <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png">

Comment: @ArtemBozhko Thanks for checking the code, i used `var font = "<img src = 'https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png'>";` & kept other `font` related code to display dynamically , i think i done some wrong there or is the approach i used is wrong ?

Comment: @vickeycolors You pass font variable to the mask config, but the mask function does nothing with it.

Comment: @ArtemBozhko sorry, i did't know about that.....  i passed `maskImageUrl` in mask function , so i got all the images in json file ,  in the same way i thought if i pass `font` variable, then icon also will display.... can you please guide me how to display the icons on all the images....

Comment: @vickeycolors See updates in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190313/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-artem-bozhko).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution #1**

It is possible to solve your issue using CSS.

Just add the next rule to your CSS.

```
.masked-img::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -31px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  content: url(https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png);
}
```

All the JS code related to the icon can be removed If CSS approach works for you.

The backside of this approach is that you can not change the size of the icon using CSS.

**Solution #2**

Remove `<img src = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png">` from .html file. It is useless.

Replace `var font = "<img src = 'https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png'>";` with `var imageUrl = 'https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png';`

Replace `font : font,` at line 136 with `imageUrl : imageUrl,`

Remove line 152 and 154

Swap lines `img.src = settings.imageUrl;` and `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');`

Here is the link to your project (edited): https://jsfiddle.net/Artem_Bozhko/hc39Luws/21/